# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on

Tags: rhel, rhel6

I'm facing issues while mounting the XFS file system on LINUX - RHEL 6.7.
Error I see is-

```
    [root@XXXXXXXfgd1000 ~]# mount /dev/vg00_hana/lv00_hana /hana
    mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg00_hana-lv00_hana,
           missing codepage or helper program, or other error
           In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
           dmesg | tail  or so                    

    [root@XXXXXXXfgd1000 ~]# dmesg | tail
    XFS (dm-4): bad version
    XFS (dm-4): SB validate failed
    XFS (dm-4): bad version
    XFS (dm-4): SB validate failed
    XFS (dm-4): bad version
    XFS (dm-4): SB validate failed
    XFS (dm-4): bad version
    XFS (dm-4): SB validate failed
    XFS (dm-4): bad version
    XFS (dm-4): SB validate failed
```

Steps which  followed are  -

```
    [root@XXXXXXXfgd1000 ~]# mkfs.xfs -f /dev/vg00_hana/lv00_hana
    meta-data=/dev/vg00_hana/lv00_hana isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=60293120 blks
             =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
             =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=0
    data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=241172480, imaxpct=25
             =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
    naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
    log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=117760, version=2
             =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
    realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Version Number of the xfsprogs Package is -

```
  [root@XXXXXXXfgd1000 ~]# xfs_repair -V
  xfs_repair version 4.3.0
  [root@XXXXXXXfgd1000 ~]#
```

Any suggestions to overcome this issue is much appreciated..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved.

AS I un-installed the current version of XFS package (version 4.3.0) and Subscribed to SAP HANA.  We needed SAP HANA subscription, since we are using this RHEL Image for SAP HANA Installation.

SAP HANA subscription comes with Scalable File System Add-On (XFS) at no additional charge.

This issue is resolved. Thanks